# How to retrieve email address from Pinterest Integration in android application?

Tags: android, single-sign-on, pinterest

I am able to retrieve name,image,id but could not find email.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently not possible. There is not option to get "email". :(

Comment: Think so,I went through most of there API's but still not able to find any clue for getting email.PDKUser class too doesn't contain any field for email.